# Mount LVM in rescue mode

Tags: lvm, mount, rescue-disk

I am having trouble mounting a LVM to extract a Proxmox virtual machines data. Any ideas on how I can mount it?

The data is on one of the two 2TB hard drives. I think they are RAID 1

```
root@rescue:~# mount /dev/sdd /mnt/
mount: block device /dev/sdd is write-protected, mounting read-only
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdd' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
root@rescue:~# mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
root@rescue:~#
```

Disk info

```
root@rescue:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000bf890

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        4096    40962047    20478976   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        40962048    43057151     1047552   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        43057152   468854783   212898816    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        43059200   468854783   212897792   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x35f0e73a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdd: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x43bc6360

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91879 cylinders, total 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xf95db8ab

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   468862127   234430040   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/pve-data: 453.8 GB, 453760778240 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 55166 cylinders, total 886251520 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/pve-data doesn't contain a valid partition table
root@rescue:~#
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmFZh.png - Image of disks in rescue

```
root@rescue:~# pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda5  pve  lvm2 a--  203.03g 4.00g
  /dev/sdb1  pve  lvm2 a--  223.57g    0
root@rescue:~# vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  pve    2   1   0 wz--n- 426.60g 4.00g
root@rescue:~# lvs
  LV   VG   Attr     LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  data pve  -wi-ao-- 422.60g
```

Comment: Could you add the output of: `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs` ?

Comment: Added. It never detects the 2TB hard drive which is where the data is located. I think they are RAID 1

Comment: You appear to have overwritten your LVM PV with an attempt to create a software RAID. Be aware that whatever was on that volume is probably not recoverable, as the first thing that happens to a newly created software RAID array is to overwrite everything. It is time to go to your backups. If you haven't got backups, stop everything and seek help from a professional data recovery company.

Comment: Could you run `pvscan` and again those 3 commands?

Comment: Same output. I'm not sure why this happened I just rebooted and the 2TB hard drive could no longer be detected

Comment: You should clone this disk before messing with it any further. That said, give this a shot afterward; https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/mdatarecover.html.